# How to combine 2 results from SQL procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote a SQL query, it is 300+ line and I made this as a procedure.

I want to run two times this procedure with different parameters and then want to see all result in one table.

For example:

```
exec sp_xxxxx 4652,'2022-02-07 00:00:00.000',1 
// Returns 2 columns, number of rows can vary

exec sp_xxxxx 4652,'2022-02-14 00:00:00.000',1
// Returns 2 columns, number of rows can vary
```

I run these together, then I hope to get a result of 4 columns

// 4 column,number of rows can vary

I tried `openrowset` but SQL blocked.

How can I do this, I would be very happy if you can help.

Comment: You want 4 columns, so you want to join the results in some way.

Comment: I couldn't find that some way part

Comment: Put the results into temp tables then join them.

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information to provide a demonstrable solution, but the approach should be:

```
Create temp table #T1(col1, col2)
Create temp table #T2(col1, col2)

Insert into #T1(col1, col2) exec proc
Insert into #T2(col1, col2) exec proc

select t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col1, t2.col2
from #T1 inner/left/full join #T2 on<criteria>
```

Also note that prefixing procedures with "sp" is not recommended, this is reserved by MS and indicates a Special Procedure. Choose a different prefix - or no prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Start with creating a table type than matches the output of your procedure.
For example:

```
CREATE TYPE XxxxxTblType AS TABLE(
 Col1 varchar(10) not null, 
 Col2 decimal(8,2) not null
);
```

*This table type could also be used by your procedure.*

Then use a variable with that table type to collect the results from the procedures. Then create a temporary table from that table variable.

```
declare @Xxxxx XxxxxTblType;
insert into @Xxxxx exec sp_xxxxx 4652,'2022-02-07 00:00:00.000',1;
insert into @Xxxxx exec sp_xxxxx 4652,'2022-02-14 00:00:00.000',1;

select * into #tmpXxxxx from @Xxxxx;
```

Now you can query the temporary table.

```
select * from #tmpXxxxx;
```